# adding new value to stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stream of data and I want to add new value to an existing stream.
Code looks like this

```
Stream<List<Points>> _points;
_points.sink.add(values);
```

is this possible, or do I have to find a different way?

Comment: `StreamGroup()..add(_points)..add(anotherStream)`

Comment: You may be looking for a `StreamController` -https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/StreamController-class.html

Answer (score 3):

You can send data to a stream using the sink in a [`StreamController`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) as well as [add existing streams to the controller](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/StreamController/addStream.html)

```dart
// Create controller
final streamController = StreamController<List<Point>>();

// Listen to stream
streamController.stream.listen((points) { doStuff(points); });

// Send data to stream
streamController.sink.add([const Point(0.0, 0.0), const Point(1.0, 1.0)]);

// You can also add other streams to the controller
streamController.addStream(otherStream);
```